# I got syntax error for SQL on java, where there isn't any error 

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

Yeah,this is reall weired, we are using microsoft access 2010 for java ... then here is my printout sql statement

DB Query:

```
INSERT INTO FileShare(source,destination,date)
VALUES ('C:\Users\JunHai\Documents\Scenario.docx',
          'C:\Users\JunHai\Desktop\dfdfd.docx','29/01/2011 00:34:33')
```

It totally seems alright, but it just keeping giving me syntax error ... who can really see the problem ?

Comment: Whats the syntax error? And post the Java Code who call it.

Comment: Date's a reserved name, you'll have to surround it with backticks

Comment: Post it as an answer @marc-b, the questoin deserves one, but it feels wrong to post you answer :)

Comment: *Microsoft Access 2010 for Java*: just radiates efficiency.

Answer (score 4):

Date's a reserved name, you'll have to surround it with backticks (`)

Comment: If this is being inserted into an Access database using JDBC, why to you use back ticks and not square brackets - [Date] - which would be standard for MS Access?